# Create a new Pandas dataframe from column of lists

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in a Pandas dataframe (length=32000) where each row contains a list of exactly 1,200 items.

```
    data['data']
    
    0        [206, 195, 187, 183, 177, 175, 174, 193, 198, ...
    1        [215, 209, 200, 196, 192, 197, 205, 168, 155, ...
    2        [204, 214, 220, 219, 213, 205, 198, 193, 199, ...
    3        [179, 174, 179, 178, 173, 170, 168, 168, 168, ...
    4        [222, 222, 218, 214, 208, 205, 207, 206, 206, ...
                                   ...                        
    31995    [217, 197, 206, 221, 219, 200, 202, 222, 231, ...
    31996    [184, 198, 218, 222, 220, 216, 216, 215, 210, ...
    31997    [121, 121, 119, 117, 119, 112, 118, 117, 126, ...
    31998    [172, 190, 202, 202, 196, 193, 188, 191, 199, ...
    31999    [161, 172, 189, 190, 178, 151, 156, 171, 174, ...
    Name: data, Length: 32000, dtype: object
```

How would I transform this column and split up the list to create a new DataFrame of shape 32000x1200? I have tried creating a new dataframe (`X = pd.DataFrame(data['data'])`
), but the shape of this is 32000x1.

Comment: Wild guess : `pd.DataFrame(data['data'].tolist())` ?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Anky! `pd.DataFrame(data['data'].tolist())` worked perfectly.